# Excel 2007 VBA: Selecting Sheet With a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a sheet based on a variable.

From a top level, I have a For loop driven by the variable Num = 1 To 18
The variable "CurrentSN" changes value based on a list of serial numbers on sheet ("SN's").

```
Dim Num As Integer 
Dim CurrentSN As String

CurrentSN = Sheets("SN's").Cells(Num, 1).Value
```

18 pre-existing sheets are in the workbook, each named with one of these serial numbers (18 total). I want to refer to the appropriate sheet for each loop so I used...

```
Sheets(CurrentSN).Range("A1").Select
```

Unfortunately, it is erroring out on this line. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do inside your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must activate the sheet before you can select something on it. Use
`Sheets(CurrentSN).Activate`
before
`Sheets(CurrentSN).Range("A1").Select`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a collection like the `Sheets` collection accepts two different kind of inputs:

1. A name/key
2. An index number

In your case, you want the key (the serial number), but VBA tries to retrieve the index number, as a number and not a string is provided. Therefore, you need to address your sheet with `Sheets(CStr(CurrentSN))`!

Also, Ross points out, you need to activate the sheet before your select anything in it. Though in 99.999% of the cases, you don't need so use `.Select` (and therefore `.Activate`) at all - see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm

Comment: Would just like to point out that the URL you link to is being flagged by MalwareBytes AntiMalware as potentially containing a Trojan!

Comment: @Escribblings interesting! I'll let the author know!